# How to move an object with changing the keyframe (for example position) automatically?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I want to make a lyrics video for a song. There is one part with the same rhythm but with other songtext, so I want to duplicate all the objects for the animation and move it to another position so I can change the lyrics. But if I move it the Keyframes stay in the same position...
Is there any solution for automatically change the keyframes to the new position?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this animation:

[image]

[image]

and now you want the same animation on another y-value you can do this:

select your animation, press SHIFT-D to copy all keyframes, move it with your mouse where you want to have it and you get something like this:

[image]

Now go to frame 1 and keyframe delta transform - location:

[image]

Then go 1 frame before your first copied keyframe and keyframe again:

[image]

then it looks like this:

[image]

Then change your timeline +1 frame and change the y-value (or other values as you need) and keyframe the delta again.

done.

result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to offset an animation is to sandwich in a new parent:

[image]

Here, I started with an object with a single location keyframe, animated by an f-curve modifier.  Then I duplicated the object and parented it to an empty.  Finally, I moved that empty to create the offset that I wanted.

This can be done for location, rotation, or scale offsets.

If the object is already parented to an object, you should sandwich in the new parent: parent the object to the empty, then parent the empty to the original parent of the object.

This doesn't require any kind of fiddliness or math, and can be done to eye as easily as numerically, just by controlling the new parent's transform.  There are similar techniques involving delta transforms, but deltas are a weird, out-of-date, not-quite-there solution to the problem, and so I avoid deltas whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of at this moment would be to make your duplicate, open up the Graph Editor, select the keyframes you wish to move, and <kbd>G</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to change their value (not time). You may need to hide whatever you don't want to edit or don't want to edit in the same way. Like if you want to move the `X` very far, the `Y` not so far, and the `Z` not at all, you would hide everything but `X`, select and move, deselect, then hide `X` and unhide `Y` and select and move.